# Deadlock on reorganize index

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    -- begin transaction to avoid truncate Table_Staging from parallel process
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_Staging] WITH (TABLOCK) (COLUMN1)
        SELECT COLUMN1
        FROM [Table2]
        WHERE [RegistrationDate] BETWEEN '20221101' AND '20221112' 

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        -- begin transaction to avoid reads from Table from other queries
        TRUNCATE TABLE [DB].[dbo].[Table] WITH (PARTITIONS (156));

        ALTER TABLE [DB].[dbo].[Table_Staging] 
            SWITCH PARTITION 156 TO [DB].[dbo].[Table] PARTITION 156;
        COMMIT TRANSACTION

        ALTER INDEX [ics_SplitEventAggregated]  
        ON [DB].[dbo].[Table] REORGANIZE PARTITION = 156;

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I get this error:

> Msg 1205, Level 13, State 18, Procedure sys.sp_cci_tuple_mover, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Transaction (Process ID 99) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
>
> Msg 35373, Level 16, State 1, Line 80
> ALTER INDEX REORGANIZE statement failed on a clustered columnstore index with error 1205. See previous error messages for more details.

The main question is, can I somehow run index reorganization in this logic?

Or do I have to finish all the transactions and only then do the reorganization?

Second question - why does this query get a deadlock if the previous transaction is confirmed?

Table and Table_Staging has columnstore index.

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU16) (KB5011644) - 15.0.4223.1 (X64)   
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) 
on Windows Server 2022 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 20348: )
```

Prod is on Enterprise and Standard editions.

**Update #1**

I removed TABLOCK from the query and the DEADLOCK problem disappeared. Do I understand correctly that the TABLOCK hint applies to both tables (although I only specify it in INSERT, not SELECT)?
Why does TRUNCATE TABLE work correctly then, since it also requires an exclusive lock? Or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: No, it's not empty, I'm switched new partition to it. Its just example and current logic is bigger, so I just want understand, I can do reorganize in this transaction or I need to move it away

Comment: Note: 2 BEGIN TRANSACTION statements were run prior to the COMMIT TRANSACTION. Per Microsoft, "Naming multiple transactions in a series of nested transactions with a transaction name has little effect on the transaction. Only the first (outermost) transaction name is registered with the system. "

Comment: Why do you want to reorganize your indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I somehow run index reorganization in this logic?

Yes.  But commit your whole transaction before reorganize.  Otherwise you're holding an exclusive lock on the table/partition before you start the reorganize.  This makes it more likely that some other session is blocked by your session, and that you may, in turn, become blocked by a lock held by that session.

And if the reorganize is a deadlock victim, retry or just move on.

Comment: What query hold exclusive block? Truncate? But I have commit for it

Comment: You have two BEGIN TRANSACTION but only one COMMIT before the TRUNCATE, so it hasn't really been committed yet.

Comment: So I just need to move last commit before reorganize, that is only way, right?

Comment: I'm not sure why you have multiple BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT pairs in the first place, but yes.

Comment: thank. i`m added update to question - can you look, pls?